# Gridview in C# dont show data and a big error

Tags: c#

I am trying to display my data table with a grid view

```
 protected void show_data(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;";
        str += "AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|DinoData.mdf;";
        str += "Integrated Security= True";
        SqlConnection c;
        c = new SqlConnection(str);
        GV.DataSource = User;
        GV.DataBind();
    }
```

the error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Data source is an invalid type.  It must be
>   either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource.

user table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User] (
    [Username]  VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [Pasword]   VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [FName]     VARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [LName]     VARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Location]  VARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Profesion] VARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [email]     VARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [gender]    VARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [money]     INT           NOT NULL,
    [property]  VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [xp]        INT           NOT NULL,
    [level]     INT           NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Username] ASC)
);
```

What should i do?
If I want to show only part of the table with gridview how to do it?

Comment: You don't show what `User` is but clearly it is of a wrong type

Comment: For `GV.DataSource = User;`, what is this? As the exception message suggests, you can only bind data using objects that implement those interfaces

Comment: i add the user table

Comment: For the start, what is the User? A datatable? Because the error suggests that User is not datatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no query to select rows from your database ,you must have a selection statment like :

```
   protected void show_data(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string str = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;";
            str += "AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|DinoData.mdf;";
            str += "Integrated Security= True";
            SqlConnection c;
            c = new SqlConnection(str);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            //For exemple t select all rows in you Table User,you can insert a condition here 
            String req = "SELECT * FROM [User]";
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(req, c);
            da.Fill(dt);
            GV.DataSource = dt;
            GV.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: DataTable dt = new DataTable();
shows eror on DataTable

Comment: @OzCohen yes that a simple exemple to extract data from your table User

Comment: Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DataTable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Oz Cohen you must add using System.Data; on the top of your class

Comment: ok thanks 
new problem:
An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'.

Comment: @OzCohen You must use brackets for User in query because User is a KeyWord `"SELECT * FROM [User]"`

Comment: How can i design the table? apeerient? with css?

Comment: @OzChen you can add an other question about Css ,

Comment: plss help i can post anouther quastion only in 90 minutes

Comment: Have a look at this link :http://www.parallelcodes.com/styling-the-gridview-in-asp-net/